# Rollup `buildEnd` plugin hook not getting triggered in svelte.config.js

Tags: svelte, rollup, vite, sveltekit

I need to run an operation in a custom plugin on `buildEnd` [a `roll-up` plugin build hook]

> #### buildEnd
>
> Called when rollup has finished bundling, but before generate or write is called; you can also return a Promise. If an error occurred during the build, it is passed on to this hook.

In `svelte.config.js` file, I have something very close to the following snippet but it won't trigger on `buildEnd`

```js
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
  preprocess: [
    preprocess(),
  ],
  kit: {
    floc: true,
    vite: {
      esbuild: {
        target: 'node16',
      },
      optimizeDeps: {
        exclude: [...],
      },
      plugins: [
        {
          async buildEnd() {
            // ...do something on buildEnd: doesn't work!
          },
          async buildStart() {
            // ...do something on buildStart: works!
          }
        }
      ],
    },
  },
}
```

Is there something I'm not doing right?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and `buildEnd` didn't trigger for me, for my requirements using `closeBundle` worked.

> Previous Hook: buildEnd if there was a build error, otherwise when bundle.close() is called, in which case this would be the last hook to be triggered.

https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#closebundle

```
plugins: [{
    name: 'closeBundle',
    closeBundle() {
        console.log("closeBundle");

    }
},
```

Comment: Why you should use that event in particular?

Comment: @G.Ciardini because buildEnd didn't work for me and closeBundle did work :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: added more information for the answer